# When to use std::launder?

Tags: c++, c++17, placement-new, stdlaunder

I've read a few Q/A about `std::launder` ([What is the purpose of std::launder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382501/what-is-the-purpose-of-stdlaunder), [Does this really break strict-aliasing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003727/does-this-really-break-strict-aliasing-rules), [std::launder reachability rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73376436/stdlaunder-reachability-rules)), but am still unclear whether I am using it correctly in my specific use-case.  The following is what I am trying to achieve:

```
struct Base {
    ...
};

struct Derived : Base {
    ...
};

// Declare a buffer
alignas(std::max_align_t) char buffer[2000];

// Populate the buffer using placement-new
*reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(&buffer[0]) = sizeof(Derived);
Derived *d = new (&buffer[2 * sizeof(std::max_align_t)]) Derived();
*reinterpret_cast<Base**>(&buffer[sizeof(std::max_align_t)]) = static_cast<Base*>(d);

// Extract values from the buffer
size_t s = *reinterpret_cast<size_t*  >(&buffer[0]);
Base  *b = *reinterpret_cast<Base**   >(&buffer[sizeof(std::max_align_t)]);
       d = *reinterpret_cast<Derived**>(&buffer[sizeof(std::max_align_t) * 2]);
```

My inclination is that the following is the appropriate way to `std::launder` the above statements to ensure they all result in defined behavior per the standard:

```
// Populate the buffer using placement-new
*std::launder(reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(&buffer[0])) = sizeof(Derived);
Derived *d = new (&buffer[2 * sizeof(std::max_align_t)]) Derived();
*std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Base**>(&buffer[sizeof(std::max_align_t)])) = static_cast<Base*>(d);

// Extract values from the buffer
size_t s = *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<size_t*  >(&buffer[0]));
Base  *b = *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Base**   >(&buffer[sizeof(std::max_align_t)]));
       d = *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Derived**>(&buffer[sizeof(std::max_align_t) * 2]));
```

Is the above the appropriate usage of `std::launder`?  Do I have to placement-new the `size_t` and `Base*` members prior to assigning to them?  Do I have to `std::launder` the `size_t` and `Base*` members at all?

Comment: IMO the the highest ranked answer in the first link has a very good example https://stackoverflow.com/a/39382728/6752050

Comment: That post shows an instance where they use placement-new to create an integer.  Is that placement-new required in order to result in defined behavior?  It isn't clear to me from the example.  I think the above is legal and results in defined behavior, but couldn't determine that from the examples provided, nor the language in the standard.

Comment: No, `new` is not required. It's just an example of the code, where a compiler can miss a changed value of an object. See [std::launder](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder).   
*Provenance **fence** with respect to p.*

Comment: _"Do I have to placement-new the size_t and Base* members"_ yes, technically everything has to be newed prior C++20. Practically, no.

Comment: @JeffG: Is there a reason why you don't do this in a way that isn't littered with a bunch of `reinterpret_cast`s? Like maybe making a template struct that has a size, pointer, and a `Derived` within it instead of manufacturing them piecemeal like this??

Comment: @NicolBolas I thought about making a structure, but it would have to be a template in order to support any derived type.  I am trying to make a statically-allocated template collection, that can store derived types created by calling placement-new with perfect-forwarding.  Since I don't know which of the derived types is being used, there is no struct type I could utilize to store the `size_t`, `Base*`, and `Derived`, because it wouldn't be standard-layout.  I could make the header (`size_t`, `Base*`) a struct, which would make it more readable; that is a good suggestion.

Comment: @JeffG: Take note of the second paragraph of the answer in the duplicate: "*But object lifetime is not what `std::launder` is about. `std::launder` can't be used to start the lifetime of objects.*"